# Open/close world via messages

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I looked through the Messages API and tried to use WorldModify messages like this:

- send a WorldModify message with `remove` set to `true` and `world_name` set to `default` to close the current world (also tried to reference the world with "worlds/empty.world")
- send a WorldModify message with `create` set to `true` and `world_name` set to, for example, `worlds/pioneer2dx.world` in order to open a new world

The result is that if I have the client open it crashes, otherwise (if gazebo is running headless) nothing changes. I have also tried to first pause the world then send the WorldModify messages and then do a reset with a WorldReset message but again nothing happened. I check with `gz topic -e /gazebo/world/modify` that gazebo receives the messages, so I guess I'm not using them properly.

Is it possible to open/close worlds via messages? If it is, how do you do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12912/open/close-world-via-messages/) by [gshopov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2523/gshopov/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, this functionality is not implemented in Gazebo 7 yet. But it is under active development and hopefully it will come into one of the future releases of Gazebo 7 or in Gazebo 8.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0